# Problemas renderizando html en dompdf

Tags: html, css, pdf

Buenos Días,

Estoy intentando generar un archivo pdf a través de la librería de DOMPDF, utilizando html y css.

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(utf8_decode($this->load->view('facturas/factura', $data, true)));
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($FacturaId.'.pdf', array("Attachment" => false));
```

Este es mi html: http://pastebin.com/sEWAZH9t

El problema es que recibo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando debería recibir esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso es solo problema de la manipulación del CSS, yo ocupo esa librería para generar pdfs y ningún problema, si quieres otra vez que lo uses te comparto mi código, por que veo que usaste otra finalmente.

Answer (score 0):

He solventado mi problema utilizando Libreoffice por linea de comandos:

```
$Path = APPPATH."media/Documentos/Facturas/pdf";
$FilePath = APPPATH."media/Documentos/Facturas/docx/Factura ".$FacturaId.".docx";

shell_exec(\"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe\" --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir \"".$Path."\" \"$FilePath\"");
```

Requiere tener instalado libreoffice en el servidor, pero no he logrado dar con otra opción gratuita.